# How to call the popover to show up in Safari app extension?

Tags: swift, safari-extension, safari-app-extension

I am developing a safari app extension with swift in xcode.
In my `SafariExtensionHandler.swift`, I declared a func:

```
    override func popoverViewController() -> SFSafariExtensionViewController {
        return SafariExtensionViewController.shared
    }
```

and in my `SafariExtensionViewController.swift`,

```
class SafariExtensionViewController: SFSafariExtensionViewController {

    static let shared: SafariExtensionViewController = {
        let shared = SafariExtensionViewController()
        shared.preferredContentSize = NSSize(width:320, height:240)
        return shared
    }()

}
```

However, when I click the icon in my safari toolbar, nothing shows up and no errors. 
Anyone helps? I am fresh to safari app extension and apple-family developing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Damn I figured that out.
In `info.plist`, `SFSafariToolbarItem` dict, change the value of `action` key to `Popover` .

Comment: Thank god for your post.  This was driving me mad!!

Comment: Damn this is holy crap you are lifesaver, my hero!